# Prevent Eclipse from automatically folding the import statements

Tags: java, eclipse

I searched the Eclipse settings, the web and StackOverflow, but I couldn't find an answer. Eclipse always folds the import statements and I can't turn it off.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go to Window / Preferences, type "import" into the search box, find the "Folding" section and untick "Imports".

(I love the preferences search feature. Alternatively, you can go to Java / Editor / Folding and untick it that way.)

Answer (score 20):

From the menu

```
Window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> Folding -> "Uncheck box for imports"
```

Reopen files if necessary.